# Camel ActiveMQ and JSMPP Connection Monitoring

Tags: java, apache-camel, jsmpp

We are developing an OSGI (karaf container) based application and it is deployed in fuse ESB. We have some integrations like to ActiveMQ and to SMSC over SMPP etc. We are connecting and interacting with these systems with camel routes. I want to monitor the connections status of these systems by providing a interface implementation like ***motitor(SomeMonitoringInterfaceImpl)***:

```
String url = "smpp://smppclient1@localhost:2776";
from(url).motitor(SomeMonitoringInterfaceImpl).routeId("smpp-route").to("bean:smsSmppService?method=send").end();
```

is there a way to it?

Note that the [camel-smpp component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-smpp/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/smpp/SmppConsumer.java) is trying to handle it without throwing any exception, which is understandable however which also hinders to monitor it.